# Adding the means of groups back to big dataframe without join in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this piece of code:

```py
shifted_pd = account_level_pd_shifts.filter(account_level_pd_shifts['WITHIN_PD_EXCLUSION'] == True).groupBy(['FORWARD_LOOK_MODEL', 'FOR_PD_TYPE']).agg(f.avg('PD_SHIFT').alias('SHIFTED_PD'))

account_level_pd_shifts = account_level_pd_shifts.drop('SHIFTED_PD').join(f.broadcast(shifted_pd), on=['FORWARD_LOOK_MODEL', 'FOR_PD_TYPE'], how='left')
```

I cannot do the mean of the groupby, just take the first value and then with f.lit() add it to a new column because the grouped data has 4 items, it is not 1 mean that I get, I get 4 means for each.

These 2 lines of code are in an 23 loop iteration and 23 joins is not very nice. 
Is there a way to avoid this and add the means per group directly somehow or without a join back to the big dataframe ?

I can provide extra info if unclear :)

Thanks for help

Comment: FYI. There is more code in the iteration. It is not just those 2 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is windowing function. You want to calculate a conditional average over `Window` :

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, avg


w = Window.partitionBy('FORWARD_LOOK_MODEL', 'FOR_PD_TYPE')
account_level_pd_shifts = account_level_pd_shifts.withColumn("SHIFTED_PD",
                                                              avg(when(col("WITHIN_PD_EXCLUSION"),
                                                                       col("PD_SHIFT")
                                                                   )
                                                              ).over(w)
                                                          )
```